# Receiving outlook calendar invite in BotFramework

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify, azure-bot-service

I am trying to use the Azure Bot Service to forward Outlook meeting invitations.
In the bot, I have registered an Email channel which gets a message whenever the linked mail account receives the email.
The bot is written in javascript and is a modified version of the Echo bot.
The problem is that everything related to the meeting is lost somewhere.

I think it is a problem with the fact that the calendar data isn't parsed. 
If i look at the source of the email sent, it contains a region with content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64.
However, this is not available when I try to parse the data incoming to the bot in

```
class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(context))
})
```

Basically, this context only contains the body of the email, not any additional attachments or MIME-types such as text/calendar

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look over Botbuilder-Samples [24.bot-authentication-msgraph](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph).

This official sample demonstrates how you can utilize Microsoft Graph within a bot in order to conduct Graph operations (sending/receiving email, Teams functionality, Excel operations, etc.). Among the many options, Microsoft Graph allows you to create and manage meetings easily through its APIs. And, the sample does a good job of showing you, via a couple simple calls, how to work with the data, once received.

You can experiment and test using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#). And the associated [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) are pretty well fleshed out in providing reference information, as well.

Hope of help!